# Pace.JS Qtip how to ignore the Pace Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, qtip

How we can ignore URLs with Pace.js progress animation to one of my ajax calls, 
I followed the following as mentioned in the documentation, I am trying to ignore a URL 'getTip' but it still triggers the pace animation.

```js
 ajax: {
     trackMethods: ['GET', 'POST'],
     trackWebSockets: false,
     ignoreURLs: ['arterySignalR', 'browserLink', 'getTip']
 }
```

Or how can I use the Pace.ignore in the following call:

```js
$("a[name^='qtipname']").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var id = $this.attr('rel');
    $this.qtip({
        content:{
            text: 'Loading...',
            ajax: {
                url: urlTip,
                type: 'GET', 
                loading: false,
                data: {"objectID": id}
            }
        },
        show: 'mouseover', // Show it on mouseover
        hide: {
            delay: 200,
            fixed: true // We'll let the user interact with it
        },
        style: {
            classes: 'ui-tooltip-light ui-tooltip-shadow',
            width: 290 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: try absolute path in `Pace.ignore` `ignoreURLs`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I realize this is an older post, however I recently had this requirement and this post was one of the first to come up...thought I would put my resolution here in case anyone else needs it.

Set pace options for the ignoreURLs before you load the pace.min.js library

```
<script>
    paceOptions = {
        ajax: {ignoreURLs: ['some-substring', /some-regexp/]}
    }
</script>
<script src="../dist/js/pace.min.js"></script>
```

Example of one of my ignoreURLs:

```
<script>
    paceOptions = {
        ajax: {ignoreURLs: ['staffNameAutoComplete']}
    }
</script>
<script src="../dist/js/pace.min.js"></script>
```

Where 'staffNameAutoComplete' is part of the ajax URL I am calling.

> http://www.website.com/json.php?request=staffNameAutoComplete

Comment: Thanks! The paceOptions need to be set before the script indeed. You can't change it live